# BlackBerry AbsoluteFieldManager for 4.6

Tags: blackberry, css-position

I need absolute positioning in 4.6 application, but AbsoluteFieldManager is not supported (>=5.0),
sould I create my own Manager or is there some easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own manager.